# Country name array key not defined, how can I fix this?

Tags: php, wordpress, key, undefined

I'm trying to get the country name and some other geolocalization details from the IP address and send them via CF7. I've using this code for some time now but I'm getting a warning of

> undefined array key 'country'" city, IP, etc.

I'm trying to implement it in Wordpress and it does not work. If I use the same code in an isolated PHP file, it works perfectly. I'm a bit lost about what to do. I've tried to find documentation and find a solution by myself but I'm about to give up.

Here is my code:

```
    $ip_address = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP")?:
    getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
    getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED")?:
    getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR")?:
    getenv("HTTP_FORWARDED")?:
    getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    
    //CURL init. Matchs gotten IP with API values and retrives location value.
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipinfo.io/".$ip_address."/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
    //json output.
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    //CURL close.
    curl_close($curl);
    
    //"Country code to name" array.
    $countries = array( "BD" => "Bangladesh", "BE" => "Belgium", "BF" => "Burkina Faso", "BG" => "Bulgaria", "BA" => "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BB" => "Barbados", "WF" => "Wallis and Futuna", "BL" => "Saint Barthelemy", "BM" => "Bermuda", "BN" => "Brunei", "BO" => "Bolivia", "BH" => "Bahrain", "BI" => "Burundi", "BJ" => "Benin", "BT" => "Bhutan", "JM" => "Jamaica", "BV" => "Bouvet Island", "BW" => "Botswana", "WS" => "Samoa", "BQ" => "Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba ", "BR" => "Brazil", "BS" => "Bahamas", "JE" => "Jersey", "BY" => "Belarus", "BZ" => "Belize", "RU" => "Russia", "RW" => "Rwanda", "RS" => "Serbia", "TL" => "East Timor", "RE" => "Reunion", "TM" => "Turkmenistan", "TJ" => "Tajikistan", "RO" => "Romania", "TK" => "Tokelau", "GW" => "Guinea-Bissau", "GU" => "Guam", "GT" => "Guatemala", "GS" => "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "GR" => "Greece", "GQ" => "Equatorial Guinea", "GP" => "Guadeloupe", "JP" => "Japan", "GY" => "Guyana", "GG" => "Guernsey", "GF" => "French Guiana", "GE" => "Georgia", "GD" => "Grenada", "GB" => "United Kingdom", "GA" => "Gabon", "SV" => "El Salvador", "GN" => "Guinea", "GM" => "Gambia", "GL" => "Greenland", "GI" => "Gibraltar", "GH" => "Ghana", "OM" => "Oman", "TN" => "Tunisia", "JO" => "Jordan", "HR" => "Croatia", "HT" => "Haiti", "HU" => "Hungary", "HK" => "Hong Kong", "HN" => "Honduras", "HM" => "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "VE" => "Venezuela", "PR" => "Puerto Rico", "PS" => "Palestinian Territory", "PW" => "Palau", "PT" => "Portugal", "SJ" => "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "PY" => "Paraguay", "IQ" => "Iraq", "PA" => "Panama", "PF" => "French Polynesia", "PG" => "Papua New Guinea", "PE" => "Peru", "PK" => "Pakistan", "PH" => "Philippines", "PN" => "Pitcairn", "PL" => "Poland", "PM" => "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "ZM" => "Zambia", "EH" => "Western Sahara", "EE" => "Estonia", "EG" => "Egypt", "ZA" => "South Africa", "EC" => "Ecuador", "IT" => "Italy", "VN" => "Vietnam", "SB" => "Solomon Islands", "ET" => "Ethiopia", "SO" => "Somalia", "ZW" => "Zimbabwe", "SA" => "Saudi Arabia", "ES" => "Spain", "ER" => "Eritrea", "ME" => "Montenegro", "MD" => "Moldova", "MG" => "Madagascar", "MF" => "Saint Martin", "MA" => "Morocco", "MC" => "Monaco", "UZ" => "Uzbekistan", "MM" => "Myanmar", "ML" => "Mali", "MO" => "Macao", "MN" => "Mongolia", "MH" => "Marshall Islands", "MK" => "Macedonia", "MU" => "Mauritius", "MT" => "Malta", "MW" => "Malawi", "MV" => "Maldives", "MQ" => "Martinique", "MP" => "Northern Mariana Islands", "MS" => "Montserrat", "MR" => "Mauritania", "IM" => "Isle of Man", "UG" => "Uganda", "TZ" => "Tanzania", "MY" => "Malaysia", "MX" => "Mexico", "IL" => "Israel", "FR" => "France", "IO" => "British Indian Ocean Territory", "SH" => "Saint Helena", "FI" => "Finland", "FJ" => "Fiji", "FK" => "Falkland Islands", "FM" => "Micronesia", "FO" => "Faroe Islands", "NI" => "Nicaragua", "NL" => "Netherlands", "NO" => "Norway", "NA" => "Namibia", "VU" => "Vanuatu", "NC" => "New Caledonia", "NE" => "Niger", "NF" => "Norfolk Island", "NG" => "Nigeria", "NZ" => "New Zealand", "NP" => "Nepal", "NR" => "Nauru", "NU" => "Niue", "CK" => "Cook Islands", "XK" => "Kosovo", "CI" => "Ivory Coast", "CH" => "Switzerland", "CO" => "Colombia", "CN" => "China", "CM" => "Cameroon", "CL" => "Chile", "CC" => "Cocos Islands", "CA" => "Canada", "CG" => "Republic of the Congo", "CF" => "Central African Republic", "CD" => "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "CZ" => "Czech Republic", "CY" => "Cyprus", "CX" => "Christmas Island", "CR" => "Costa Rica", "CW" => "Curacao", "CV" => "Cape Verde", "CU" => "Cuba", "SZ" => "Swaziland", "SY" => "Syria", "SX" => "Sint Maarten", "KG" => "Kyrgyzstan", "KE" => "Kenya", "SS" => "South Sudan", "SR" => "Suriname", "KI" => "Kiribati", "KH" => "Cambodia", "KN" => "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KM" => "Comoros", "ST" => "Sao Tome and Principe", "SK" => "Slovakia", "KR" => "South Korea", "SI" => "Slovenia", "KP" => "North Korea", "KW" => "Kuwait", "SN" => "Senegal", "SM" => "San Marino", "SL" => "Sierra Leone", "SC" => "Seychelles", "KZ" => "Kazakhstan", "KY" => "Cayman Islands", "SG" => "Singapore", "SE" => "Sweden", "SD" => "Sudan", "DO" => "Dominican Republic", "DM" => "Dominica", "DJ" => "Djibouti", "DK" => "Denmark", "VG" => "British Virgin Islands", "DE" => "Germany", "YE" => "Yemen", "DZ" => "Algeria", "US" => "United States", "UY" => "Uruguay", "YT" => "Mayotte", "UM" => "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "LB" => "Lebanon", "LC" => "Saint Lucia", "LA" => "Laos", "TV" => "Tuvalu", "TW" => "Taiwan", "TT" => "Trinidad and Tobago", "TR" => "Turkey", "LK" => "Sri Lanka", "LI" => "Liechtenstein", "LV" => "Latvia", "TO" => "Tonga", "LT" => "Lithuania", "LU" => "Luxembourg", "LR" => "Liberia", "LS" => "Lesotho", "TH" => "Thailand", "TF" => "French Southern Territories", "TG" => "Togo", "TD" => "Chad", "TC" => "Turks and Caicos Islands", "LY" => "Libya", "VA" => "Vatican", "VC" => "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "AE" => "United Arab Emirates", "AD" => "Andorra", "AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda", "AF" => "Afghanistan", "AI" => "Anguilla", "VI" => "U.S. Virgin Islands", "IS" => "Iceland", "IR" => "Iran", "AM" => "Armenia", "AL" => "Albania", "AO" => "Angola", "AQ" => "Antarctica", "AS" => "American Samoa", "AR" => "Argentina", "AU" => "Australia", "AT" => "Austria", "AW" => "Aruba", "IN" => "India", "AX" => "Aland Islands", "AZ" => "Azerbaijan", "IE" => "Ireland", "ID" => "Indonesia", "UA" => "Ukraine", "QA" => "Qatar", "MZ" => "Mozambique" );
    
    //Assigns values to the variable "$ip_details".
    $ip_details = json_decode($output, true);
    
    //Global variables for further use.
    $country_name = $countries[$ip_details["country"]]; //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.
    $ip_json = $ip_details["ip"]; //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.
    $city = $ip_details["city"]; //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.
    $region = $ip_details["region"]; //HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR.
```

P.D. I'VE READ ABOUT USING isset()... and some how it makes sense to me.

Comment: If `$ip_details` doesn't contain these keys, what *does* it contain?  When you debug, what is the observed runtime value of `$ip_details` and/or `$output`?

Comment: I thought about that. but I tested the code on an isolated PHP page and it does the job. I'm so confused. Here is the link the the test page. http://rafaeloliveros.com/classroom/country/

Comment: You thought about debugging and observing the runtime value... but decided not to?  Indeed you may be a bit confused.  If the problem is that the value of `$ip_details` isn't what you expect it to be then your next debugging step would be to observe what actual value it has when the error occurs.

Comment: For future reference, please post ACTUAL error messages and not a summary. We work better from accurate info

Comment: Did you notice, if you pass a bad ip address your response is like this `Array
( [ip] => 100.100.100.100, [bogon] => 1 )`  So maybe you should check for a occurance of `bogon` before assuming you will get a good reply